# Why might the user's email address not show up in Views Send or as a Token?

Tags: tokens, views

I have set up a User view, with User: Email as one of the fields (the others are username and some text fields) .  The email address of each user shows correctly in the view, either formatted as text, or as a link.

I was hoping to use Views Send to send an email from that view.  When I tick the Views Send tickbox and click 'send email' the dropdown displayed against 'Field used for recipient's e-mail' shows all the fields in the view apart from the email field.

I tried pulling in another text field and rewriting that to show [user:mail] or [mail] as a Token, but the rewritten field is empty.

I've been all around the houses trying to work out why that field is not showing in the dropdown and I'm stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAY!

I finally managed to find out why this was happening by comparing against two other Drupal sites where Views Send behaved as expected.

The issue was with the Views Contact Form module : https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/views_contact_form

If you have that enabled, it breaks Views Send by hiding the main user email address, even if you have the format of the field set to plain text.